# How to display success message at the top while its in inside div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a form on my website where users can post anything. After they submit it the success message is showing, and I want to display that success message at the top of the page, but I can't because it's inside another div, so it can be displayed just in that div.

**Index**

```
<section id="page-title">

    <?php if ($msgDiv) { echo $msgDiv; } ?> <!-- This is how I display my success or warning alert box -->

    <div class="container" id="container2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 title togglePanel">
                <div class="row">
                <!-- rest of code -->
```

**PHP for the alert box:**

```
/* missed code */
                $stmt->execute();
                $msgDiv = alertBox($confPosted,"", "success");
                // Clear the Form of values
                $_POST['firstName'] = $_POST['confessText'] = $_POST['answer'] = '';
                $stmt->close();
            }
        } else {
            $msgDiv = alertBox($captchaErrorMsg, "<i class='fa fa-warning'></i>", "warning");
            $toggleOpen = ' in';
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is big, but I can't display it at the top of the page because it's inside page-title (the form section), and if I put it outside it won't even show.

So I want my success message which appears after submitting a form to show on the top of the page and not inside that div.

Is that something that needs to be done in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you add message div directly in body

```
<body>
    <div class='message'> This is the message </div>
    ...
</body>
```

and add style

```
.class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

and then just add an event that should trigger display property.

Comment: Brate kako? Success poruka mi je u divu gde je forma i kad ispune formu redirektuje ih opet na istu stranicu i pokazuje success poruku u tom divu, a ja hocu da pokaze cak gore. Znaci ja imam vec success poruku koja radi samo hocu da je pokazem cak gore.

Comment: Jel imas neki kod da pokazes pa cu da ti skrpim nesto preko codepena. U sustini ako hoces da ti se poruka prikaze na vrhu stranice nije bitno gde se nalazi u html-u dokle god im parent element nema position: absolute, relative, fixed.
Ukoliko parent nema ove tagove onda stavis u css-u dodas position: absolute; i sam pomeras poruku po stranici gde god hoces. 
Kad budes video primer bice ti jasno

Comment: Pa brate ne znam sta da stavim kao kod, generalno to je button gde kliknes i slajduje ti da napises nesto, kad napises redirektuje na pocetnu i samo pokaze success poruku iznad buttona koji je u tom divu gde je i forma i sve. A pokusao sam sa position absolute ali nece a niko od parenta nema absolute, relative etc...

Comment: Pretpostavljam da zelis da se trigeruje kad uspesno submitujes formu.
Tada treba da trigerujes event koji ce pozvati funkciju recimo `messageSuccess()`.
 Ta funkcija treba da ima samo dodeljivanje klase koja u sebi ima `display: block;` i `setTimeout(someFunction(){ ove ide kod koji ce da ukloni klasu koja je dodeljena }, 3000)` . setTimout ti omogucava da sklonis tu poruku posle 3000ms(3 sekunde). 
Sto se tice html/css poruka treba da se nalazi unutar forme ukoliko zelis da se nalazi iznad buttona i mora da u css da ima property `display: none;`

malo je teze bez primera da se objasni

Comment: Brate vec se trigeruje poruka, kad posalju poruku stize im success poruka, samo sto se pojavljuje unutar ovog diva i nikako ne mogu da je stavim cak gore na stranici. Je l' imas mozda neki mejl pa mogu da ti posaljem kod kako izgleda i slike neke od sajta pa bi verovatno znao o cemu se radi. U pitanju je samo html css problem, sto se tice funkcionalnosti sve radi, samo ne mogu da je stavim gde ja hocu. Hvala na pomoci inace!

Comment: ajde sibaj na neccymaradona@yahoo.com